# Cannot run MetaAI's llama2 due to "No module named 'fire'" error

Tags: python, import, pytorch, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to run the llama2 model locally on my MacOS (M1 chip).

In the `example_chat_completion.py` file there is an import for the fire module:

```
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
# This software may be used and distributed according to the terms of the Llama 2 Community License Agreement.

from typing import List, Optional

import fire

from llama import Llama, Dialog

...
```

But when attempting to run the model as instructed from the [llama2 repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama):

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_chat_completion.py \
    --ckpt_dir llama-2-7b-chat/ \
    --tokenizer_path tokenizer.model \
    --max_seq_len 512 --max_batch_size 6
```

...I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fire'
```

I am running from `llama` directory, and have tried `pip install fire`, `pip3 install fire`, `conda install fire` and  `python -m pip install fire`. All of these methods show "Requirement already satisfied."

Note that I am running in the [venv-metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) virtual environment.

Comment: It could be the difference in virtual environment that causes the issue since the documentation suggests using conda instead of venv-metal. Did you encounter any issues with conda env?

Comment: I have the same issue and I am using conda

Comment: same problem... fire not found, firescale not found.. I installed them

Answer (score 0):

@cybernetic, did you run the following command line in the root of the llama repository?

## How to correct the issue?

1. run the command `pip install -e .`
2. run the torchrun command in the root directory

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_chat_completion.py \
    --ckpt_dir llama-2-7b-chat/ \
    --tokenizer_path tokenizer.model \
    --max_seq_len 512 --max_batch_size 6
```